# How to implement local logout in SAML-based SSO app using G Suite as IDP

Tags: java, spring-security, saml-2.0, logout, google-workspace

I have implemented Single Sign on to my own app, using G Suite, and it works.

I used this library:
https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/spring-boot-security-saml 
in order to integrate spring-security-saml with spring boot.

But when I try to logout, calling scheme://server:port/contextPath/saml/logout?local=true as described here: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-logout-local 
(in section 9.3.1) - nothing happens. (The user is redirected to the default logout page which is configured, but he is still logged in. He can get any page he wants without reauthenticate).

Dubugging code shows that SecurityContextLogoutHandler set null value to the local Authentication object, but SAMLProcessingFilter triggers automatically authentication process with the IDP(which still holds the Authentication) and the user is authenticated again(although he did logout).

Did someone encounter this problem before?
Thanks!